# Sql reports with BI Studio (BIDS) , I want one Entry per Page

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reporting, business-intelligence

Imagine I have 10 Categories. For each categories I have many Products.

**Category**
CategoryID(PK)
CategoryName 
CategoryDescription

**Product** 
ProductID(PK)
CategoryID(FK) 
ProductName
ProductPrice 
ProductDescription
ProductNumber

I would like to have 1 page per category.
On each page, I want the category name, the category Descripton.
And in a Table, I want the Product list.

How Can I perform this ?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are your products related to your categories?  It isn't clear from the info you provided.

Comment: Hi add some info under each of table. There is a foreingh key between product and category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a query that gives you the information you want.  This will be saved as your dataset within the report.  This could be as simple as

```
SELECT c.CategoryName, 
  c.CategoryDescription, 
  p.ProductName, 
  p.ProductPrice, 
  p.ProductDescription, 
  p.ProductNumber
FROM Category c
JOIN Product p ON --insert join criteria here... like c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
```

Name that dataset Products.

Next, drag a table onto your report.  Define the dataset for the table to be the dataset you created above.

Create a group within the table, based on your Category primary key (CategoryName? some CategoryId?).  Order this group by CategoryName (if you want alphabetical order).

Now in your table you can put the Category Name & Category Description in the group header of the table.  All your product information will go in the table detail rows.

This will get you started.  You can options at the group level to start a new page at the beginning of each group.  You can also put in running totals (sums, averages, etc) that reset at a change in group.

Comment: Thanks, the broup by is maginc in the BI Studio, I Use a list tool to have one row per page